# What is the best way to type predicate for large object types?

Tags: typescript, typeguards

[In typescript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) they have given the example for type predicate with objects that have only one method on them.

Now let's consider following hypothetical code sample:

```js
const oneOfLargeObjects: unknown = getRandomLargeObject();

if (isMyLargeObject(oneOfLargeObjects)) {
  // do something with MyLargeObject type
 } else {
  // another large object
}
```

Here, let's say  type has lots of fields in it.
Is there anyway to escape from writing such function? It seems unmanageable to me.

```js
function isMyLargeObject(obj: unknown): obj is MyLargeObject {
  return (
    typeof obj?.strField === 'string' &&
    typeof obj?.numField === 'number' &&
    typeof obj?.boolField === 'boolean'
    /// lots of other field checks
  );
}
```

Comment: The bare minimum seems at least the mandatory fields, optionals may or may not be there, so no need to check these. For the rest, there is no much way out to be 100% sure.

Comment: See the linked question and answers for more information.  You either need to use some kind of code-generating build step, or you can write/use a library to generate both your interfaces and type guards from a schema object (like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wjQ9lW), for example)

Comment: great reference! Thanks @jcalz.